# Android first run-like circle indicator

Tags: android

So I want to show the circle thing, explanation and ok button on the first boot of my app. How do I do this? Any tutorial would help. I've seen them in many apps such as 알람매미 thats Korean by the way

I can't put images...
something like the image on this link
http://blog.lbfctry.com/2013/01/01/getting-started-on-androids-adt-bundle-on-mac-osx/android-emulator-first-boot/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ShowCaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView) Library.

https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/raw/master/example.png[image]

From the [wiki](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/wiki/_pages), the setup is quite easy.

```
ShowcaseView.insertShowcaseView(R.id.get_started_button, this, "Get started", "Touch button to begin set-up", null);
```